# How do i name my mongodb table in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, unicorn

Ok so i have a rails app using mongoid and I have these settings in my mongoid file for the production database

```
# set these environment variables on your prod server
production:
  host: <%= ENV['MONGOID_HOST'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PORT'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['MONGOID_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PASSWORD'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['MONGOID_DATABASE'] %>
```

How does this work and how do i name the database something specific in my rails 3.2.3 app

Comment: Where are you hosting your app? Heroku? Own server?

Comment: own server...its on amazon ec2

Answer (score 0):

The above is using environment variables

You could remove the <%= ENV part and replace with just
'myDatabaseName' 
If you wanted it to be fairly static

Same goes for username / password etc

I'd suggest reading up on running your app using environment variables however, as it will offer a bit more flexibility

Comment: i am on a ubuntu 11.10 on amazon ec2 and i want to know how to create the database using these environment variables...Do you have a link or something that might explain this more

Comment: are you connecting via SSH to your server?
you'll need to create the db using mongo shell - see mongodb website

then set environment variables on your web server.
or edit your config file to add the name / details statically